# what is the role of /system/app on Android?

Tags: android

I am looking to clear space on /system on my Android device.  It turns out that /system/app is using almost 35% of the space on /system.  I find that if I delete an apk from /system/app, nothing seems to happen to the application.  It does not get uninstalled, and it still runs fine.  Therefore, what is the role of /system/app ?  Is it some sort of cache?  Can I clear everything in it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is off topic here, but I'm answering to prevent a disaster in your phone:

### it is the folder where the system apps reside!!!

You may be OK removing one or two unused APKs, but if you remove anything else, your phone will be useless.

BTW, next time, try android.stackexchange.com

Grab Titanium Backup app from the market, and make a full backup of the system apps. You can then start deleting some apps from the system folder, and use the backup in case you need it back.
There's even a "create an update.zip" option to add a recovery zip in case you cannot even boot.

The reason you see some apps still running is because you probably have another installation in /data/app , most probably some update from the market.

Comment: thanks, but why is Twitter.apk in /system/app then? or GoogleGoggles?  Those are not necessarily system apps.

Comment: another example, I deleted GoogleGoggles.apk from /system/app and it still runs without issue.

Comment: I don't know what phone/ROM do you have. Most ROMs will come with a set of accessory apps (such as twitter or goggles) and all of them will go to /system/app since are "factory installed". Yes, you may delete them, specially because you can get those from the market again. But don't delete anything you don't know what it is.

Comment: I think I need to clarify.  I delete /system/app/GoogleGoggles.apk.  However, GoogleGoggles is still installed on my system even after deleting that.  And it still runs without issue.

Comment: OK, I saw your other question about the huge lib so I'm more inclined to help a little more here :)

Comment: thanks for the help!  I'm slowly deleting things and I don't see an impact on the system yet... I did a ROM backup incase the phone borks out in the meantime.

Comment: OK. Good luck! Check the solution to the other Q also.

Comment: Okay, once I deleted Maps.apk, maps was removed from my system.  There was no update for it in /data/app ... so parts of it are live like you mentioned!

Comment: Well, don't try to remove Contacts.apk! Going to bed now. Bye!